# Exclude red status tags on the Users pages of meta

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, meta, users

I've noticed that the normal required tags such as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) are already excluded in these lists, but why are the red status tags such as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) not also excluded? They don't really go to identify which tags the user is active in, only that they post a lot in feature requests and bug reports that get acted upon, as demonstrated by the first page of the Users page:

[image: It's been over-run by status-completed!]

I would much rather see another tag they're often involved in there rather than seeing that everyone is involved in the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag. The same could be said for the [stackoverflow](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow) tag. Although, once MSE comes along, that tag should for the most part die off. For example:

[image: Tim Stone's interesting vs not interesting tags]

Comment: Maybe we could do this since it's only metas (it's an intensive performance problem on Stack Overflow itself), will throw it to the team on the call and see what others think.

Comment: I agree. As those tags are only for the status of the bug/feature report, showing them doesn't say anything about the type of questions answered from users, except (for example) they answer to questions asking for something that has been already implemented.

Comment: +1 for pixtures with awesome lines!

Comment: wow, your freehand text is *really* good!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This change will go out in the next build: required *and* mod-only tags won't be looked for `/users` on metas (yay for not having to worry about SO scale performance!).